# Deploy and debug a remote Linux Docker container using Visual Studio Tools for Docker

Tags: debugging, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to figure out how I can deploy to a remote container using *Visual Studio Tools for Docker*, and debug my ASP.NET Core app.

Actually, I'm working in the following scenario:

- My dev machine is an Hyper-V VM.
- Docker is installed on the host machine where the whole VM/Dev machine is running at <sup>(1)</sup>

I believe that Visual Studio 2017 doesn't cover this use case, but I'm looking for realizing if I can tweak it to workaround this limitation.

<sup>(1) **I installed Docker on the host machine because my CPU doesn't support nested virtualization**</sup>

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm interested in using a similar setup with Docker and my dev VM both running as guests on a Hyper-V host.

Comment: @Jacob Nope :(!

Comment: I am in a similar situation, did you find an answer?

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I'll return to Docker once the solution I'm working on have been considered ready to production...