# How to debug .net Core project with Docker support, using Visual Studio on a remote docker server

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

There are many similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281118/deploy-and-debug-a-remote-linux-docker-container-using-visual-studio-tools-for-d), but my scenario is slightly different.

I use Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, dotnet Core app 2.0, on a Windows 10 Pro machine, where is running docker for windows.

I can run and debug my applications in my local machine's docker server, but now I would like to configure visual studio, for my current project only, to run the application in another docker server.

So in practice instead of running commands such as docker run, docker build and so on, I would like it to use docker --tls -H={theotherdockerserver} build ...

I could not find so far any parameter or configuration section that allows me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all your files accessible from remote server. One way to do this is to put your code in GitHub repository and run command: `docker --tls -H={dockerserver} build https://github.com/{user}/{repository}.git`

[Documentation for GitHub build.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories)

Do you need an option without GitHub repository?

Comment: thanks for replying. I already do this, and the source code can be in my machine (check this for more detail: https://github.com/norcino/docker-dotnet-core-api-qnap-nas).
In my case what I would like to do is to be able to hit F5 on Visual Studio and debug a container running not on my machine, but instead in another Docker server.
I have no idea how to configure, if possible, Visual Studio to do so.